# JQuery how to temporarily remove/addClass to a page?

Tags: jquery, html

It seems to me that `.remove()` and `.addClass()` are permanent modification to the html.

For example, if I have two panes in a site, each loads its own page, `p1.html` and `p2.html`. In p1.html, there is a button, which can remove/addClass to a `<div>` in `p2.html`.

I realize that once I click on the button, that  is permanently changed. Now if I have two buttons, when I click on the second button after clicking on the first one, I expect the change to be restored before clicking on the second button. I want to avoid hard coding it such as reversing the modification since the modification itself if removing/adding a long code of `<div class>....</div>`

This is more of a design question rather than code debugging. I apologize for the reading.

Comment: Ever heard of `.toggle()` and `.toggleClass()`?

Comment: You understand that [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) is not the inverse operation of [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) correct? I think you may be looking for [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) or possibly even [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) as @DJDavid98 pointed out above...

Comment: Also of interest, if you do want to remove a block of elements from the DOM with the intent to re-add that element block later, you may want to look into [`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)...

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve - some code including what  (or a representation there of) you are adding/removing would help. But I'll also re-iterate that `remove()` and `addClass()` are not antonyms and have completely different use cases.

Comment: Any change will affect the underlaying HTML code. But if you have the className saved and handy, you can add/remove class at will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `.remove()` on something, that something is *removed* from the DOM.  So to undo that change you would indeed have to add it back to the DOM in its entirety.

If you just want to *hide* that element, then just do that:

```
$('#someElement').hide();
```

Then later you can re-show it:

```
$('#someElement').show();
```

Or you can combine the two into a single call which would hide what's shown and show what's hidden:

```
$('#someElement').toggle();
```

That way the elements are still part of the DOM, they're just styled to not be displayed until you want to display them again.

---

Or, for explicitly toggling classes instead of the display of the whole element, use `removeClass()`, `addClass()`, and/or `toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 2):

`$(selector).removeClass(className)` will remove the class

`$(selector).addClass(className)` will add the class

`$(selector).hasClass(className)` will check if the class exist

`$(selector).toggleClass(className, flag)` will check and add/remove the class based on the flag

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear (to me at least) based on your question what you are trying to accomplish. However, there are a few options you can try to accomplish what you want. First though, to clear things up, understand that `.remove()` is not the inverse operation of `.addClass()`.

**Option 1:**

If you're wanting to alternate between adding and removing a class, you can use:

```
$(selector).addClass(classname);
```

to add a class, or:

```
$(selector).removeClass(classname);
```

You can also toggle a given class like so:

```
$(selector).toggleClass(classname);
```

**Option 2:**

If you do indeed want to remove a group of elements from the DOM with the intent to reattach the elements later, you can try the following:

```
var $elements = $(selector).detach();
```

This detaches the elements but keeps their associated data and event handlers. These elements can then be reattached later using this method:

```
$(parent).append($elements);
```

or:

```
$elements.appendTo(parent);
```